# How to use scanf in for loop as a condition in c programming language

Tags: c, loops, scanf

As in the following codes I did not understand usage of `scanf` in `for` loop.

How can I use or what it does when i use it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char word[10];
int count[10] = {0};

printf("Enter text:\n");

for(scanf("%s", word); word[0] != '.'; scanf("%s", word)) {
    int len;

    for(len = 0; word[len] != '\0'; len++);
        count[len]++;
}

int i;
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("There are %d words with %d letters\n", count[i], i);
}
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting first.

Comment: what do you mean ? code formatting ?

Comment: @Unknown code formatting: some one edited your question. Now the code is formatted. Do you see the difference?

Comment: i see that. Thank you .

Comment: This is the second 'explain the clever, cool code' question this morning.  If devs. would stop writing it, it would not continually appear on SO:(

Comment: @MartinJames It's not clever, and it's not cool. `while(*s++ = *t++) ;` is clever and cool.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider you are, of course, correct:)  If only it was universally seen that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop has three parts. The first part is always executed first, and never executed again. So doing

```
for(scanf("%s", word); word[0] != '.'; scanf("%s", word)) {
```

is basically equivalent to

```
scanf ("%s", word);
for(; word[0] != '.'; scanf("%s", word)) {
```

If you're not understanding how a `for` loop works, see the flowchart:

[image]

<sub>([Source](http://pics.c4learn.com/2012/01/For-Loop-Statement-in-C-Programming1.png))</sub>

If you want a tutorial, see [this tutorial on loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm).

Answer (score 2):

In general, a for loop has the following structure:

```
for (part1; part2; part3) {
    ....
}
```

- **Part 1** is a statement which is *executed once, before the loop starts*. After its execution, you get into the loop and its statements start to execute. This part is mainly used for initializations useful for the loop. If you leave it empty, you simply do not do any action before the loop.
- **Part 2** is the *condition you check at each iteration*.
- **Part 3** is a statement which is e*xecuted at the end of each iteration*.

So here, Part 1 is the statement `scanf("%s", word);`, which means that initially you read a string before you get into the loop. After every iteration, you check the condition and Part 3 is again the statement `scanf("%s", word);`. Consequently, after every iteration you read a new string (and then use it in your condition).

Actually, this loop is equivalent to

```
scanf("%s", word);
while(word[0] != '.')
{
    int len;

    for(len = 0; word[len] != '\0'; len++);
        count[len]++;
    scanf("%s", word);
}
```

Comment: Using the term "command" is really confusing. They're called statements, in C. There are also expressions.

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather ugly loop. Since the for loop is designed to allow any form of expression both in the 1st and 3rd clause, it works. That doesn't mean you should be writing code like that though.

The loop is equivalent to:

```
scanf("%s", word);
while(word[0] != '.')
{
  ...
  scanf("%s", word);
}
```

I would suggest you use `while` instead.

Comment: I find a solution better which tests the return value of `scanf` (your loop may run forever!) and avoids repeating it... but then I'm probably biased ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yes that's better but the original code didn't do that either. One thing at a time. I can add a second example with error checking, it is trivial to modify the code.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Actually, proper code should also check against buffer size... in which case scanf is just annoying to use. Proper code would use fgets.

Comment: Buffer size: true.

Answer (score 0):

A usual `for.. loop` is as such: `for(DO_ONCE_WHEN_THE_LOOP_STARTS; CONDITION_TO_CONTINUE ; DO_AT_END_OF_EACH_ITERATION) {STATEMENTS;}`.

In the code above,`scanf("%s",word)` is executed at the `start of the loop`, and at the `end of every iteration of the loop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(scanf("%s", word); word[0] != '.'; scanf("%s", word)) 
    {
      int len;

      for(len = 0; word[len] != '\0'; len++);
      count[len]++;
    }
```

Syntax of the `for loop` is `for(initialization;condition;increments/decrements)`

- in the code first `scanf()` in for loop is taking the input from the user and in `word as a string`
- then the condition is getting checked whether `word[0]` is `.` or not
- then in increment `scanf()` again the new string is getting read at run time

**So the `scanf()` used in the `for() loop` is to read the input at run time**

Answer (score 0):

I can understood from your for loop is that

```
for(scanf("%s", word); word[0] != '.'; scanf("%s", word))
```

you are going to input strings and count the number of words and letters untill '.' is given as the first character of the string.

Nothing wrong in this for loop, because after getting each string you are checking with the '.' and counting according to it.

May be not the proper way of coding, but can work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that common to use complicated function calls directly in loop statements because it may impair readability. (An example for a simple function call is K&R's famous `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.)

That said, I would prefer the `scanf` in a while loop, and test both conditions which are necessary to perform a meaningful loop action:

```
while( scanf("%9s", word) > 0 && word[0] != '.') {/* use word */}
```

The short-cutting `&&` operator tests the second condition (here: `word[0] != '.'` only if the first one was true. Here `word` is only tested if `scanf` could read something.

Using the while loop makes it clear that we are testing a condition and avoids repeating the `scanf` expression.

About your original code:

- The `for` loop wouldn't have to repeat `scanf`  if it had the `scanf` in the test (which is executed before each iteration, including the first one).
- In that case the initialization part of the for loop is empty which sometimes indicates that one could use a while loop, as I would here.
- The `scanf` result is not tested in your code, which is major bad. `scanf` returns the number of successfully converted items, which may be zero if the input doesn't match; or a negative number for EOF and I/O errors. It is essential for a correct program to test this. In your case badly formatted input or I/O errors would probably leave `word` permanently unchanged; your loop condition would never be false and the program would be called in an infinite loop.
- Lundin pointed out correctly that robust code must also make sure that `scanf` doesn't write beyond the bounds of `word`, in case the input words are longer than 9 characters. That's achieved by a maximum field length. The simple solution here does not handle such input formatting errors properly from a logical perspective (the next `scanf` will read the part of a too-long word left behind in the previous iteration), but is only a technical protection.